# Customize Rails Validation Message (Do not show attribute name) Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I'm trying to write a custom validation message in rails.

I have this validation:

```
validates_confirmation_of :password, if: :password_required?, message: I18n.t('password_confirmation.confimation')
```

The problem is: Rails is putting the attribute name in front of the message.

So, on invalid password I'm Getting: "Confirmation Password Passwords should match"

How can I get rid of the attribute name in front of the message?

Comment: What about remove the word "Passwords" from you message? Then the error message will be "Confirmation Password should match".

Comment: This is a good workaround, but doesn't answer my question. This is one case, but I have other cases where I don't want the field name to appear in the validation message.

Comment: Do you want to get message just "Passwords should match" ?

Comment: Yep. I want the message to be the one I specified. Without the attribute name.

Comment: Take a look at the code: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb#L372 The full error message is a string with attribute and message. You cannot modify that without monkey patching. The best way in this case is create a custom method validation and add error message to :base attribute: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

Comment: @dx7 Yeah. I knew this way to go.... I wanted to know if there was a way to do it without creating a custom validation method. Thnks anyway =)

Comment: There is that old gem: https://github.com/jeremydurham/custom-err-msg I don't known if that works with Rails 4.

Comment: Yeah. I've seent his gem, but compatibility is for rails 3 and ruby 1.9.

I guess there's no "easy way" to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customize the format of the error messages in your locale yml file. Just add your own format to your project.

E.g. in the file *config/locales/en.yml*:

```
en:
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"
```

See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/locale/en.yml#L4 for the original format.

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to globally change the format and show a specific message only for this one case you should handle that in the view. I don't know how exactly you are displaying the error. If you somehow use `errors.full_messages` you shouldn't in this case, which adds the format prefix. You can e.g. write a helper that gets only the error directly (`@your_model.errors[:email]`) and construct the desired output yourself.

Comment: Yes this sets the format for all validation messages. I edited my answer for a possible alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to override only certain messages in Rails 6.0+:

1. Set `config.active_model.i18n_customize_full_message = true` ([v6.0](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/configuring.html#configuring-active-model), [Edge](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-active-model-i18n-customize-full-message))
2. In your translations:

   ```yaml
   en:
     activemodel:
       errors:
         models:
           user:
             attributes:
               password_confirmation:
                 format: "%{message}"
   ```